# Use physical key input(button from headphone) to do some action in android

Tags: java, android

I have this app where I need to use a button click from the earphones and start something in my app, the problem is that I need to extend BroadcastReceiver in my class but I need the onCreate method(I extend AppCompatActivity and if I extend the BroadCastReceiver I loose the onCreate method) and because of this I cannot use the physical button from my earphones. Can you help me? Note that this is not a duplicate because I have the problem of not being able to extend the BroadCastReceiver

```
public class TrackAnimals extends AppCompatActivity{
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        setContentView(track_animals);

if(earphones button pressed){
//do something
}
```

Comment: Why do you need `onCreate`? Why can't you register a receiver in the Activity?

Comment: Is there any other way to do the findviewById to the widgets?

Comment: Not within a Receiver, no, but your question doesn't contain that method